# How to prepare a .txt file to enable pandas to encode µ symbol

Tags: python, pandas, python-unicode

I have a .txt file with a µ symbol. When using `pandas.read_table`, the µ symbol in the string is replaced by "\xb5" and pandas shows me the ?-replacement-symbol. When using `pandas.read_table(encoding="utf-8")` I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 10: invalid start byte`. How can I change the .txt file to get the right import?

Name of the first column in .txt file: 30_H2O2.20µM.

```
In [8]:pd.read_table("File.txt").columns[0]
Out[8]: '30_H2O2.20\xb5M'
In [9]:print pd.read_table("File.txt").columns[0]
30_H2O2.20�M
```

UPDATE:
encoding = "ISO-8859-1" worked!

Comment: whats problem with `data = pd.read_table('output_list.txt', sep=" ", header = None)`

Comment: the problem is, that I get such strings in the columns: u'30_H2O2.20�M'

Comment: check this: http://asciinema.org/a/80h1jr2pbw1r91wag4t0ngi25

Comment: Can you upload some part of your dataset and relative parts of your code?

Comment: I don´t understand your video

Comment: In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: print(pd.read_table("output_list.txt").columns[0])
30_H2O2.20µM